# Launch OpenStack Autopilot: Stuck "waiting for machine" while attempting to conjure-up Landscape

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I need help with conjuring-up Landscape. This is step six in the Installation instructions.

MAAS has been installed(master node), and we have 9 other machines commissioned and ready for use. Including node-Juju, node-autopilot, and a node for Openstack.

Every time I  attempt to conjure-up landscape, I get get stuck in the deployment of haproxy, landscape-server, postgresql, and rabbitmq-server, all are "waiting on machine".

How to move past waiting on machine so that landscape will be installed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet but will post this as a suggestion.

This happened to me lately. When starting to deploy the applications, conjure-up will first deploy Ubuntu on the machines you chose for the applications using MAAS, and then set up LXD containers on those machines (unless you chose not to). You can monitor the status of the deployment from the MAAS web UI. The installation of the applications will not start unless Ubuntu has been successfully deployed on the machines in question. If your machines show successful deployment, check to see of the LXD containers have been set up. If not, you would have to go through the logs on the machines to figure out the problem.

For me, deployment of Ubuntu was failing due to a misconfiguration in the machines' BIOS. Once I fixed that, everything went smoothly.

Comment: I don't have a problem successfully deploying my machines, my issue is getting Landscape to work. Landscape deploys the image on the second node, but is stuck loading the apps.

Comment: What problem was it that you faced with the BIOS? Did you manually set up your LXD containers? Did you have two NIC's for your MAAS node?

Comment: No the LXD containers were automatically set up, and yes my MAAS has two NICs from which one can reach the outside world and one is connected to the internal network to which my machines will connect. If it is of any help, I am using the MAAS for DHCP, DNS, as well as the default gateway for my commissioned machines. My BIOS problem was related to configuring power management on some very old DELL machines.

Comment: Can you try to select a different machine to deploy the applications by using the "Architect" option when starting conjure-up? This can help rule out any machine specific problems that are blocking you.

Comment: Ive exhausted all of those options @Hephaestus, Im going to step back and look at my network configuration.